# How can i connect a node js api to a mysql database located in a linux shared hosting cpanel

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux

I have looked at a lot of related questions but none actually gives an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install `mysql` in your project. And enable remote `mysql` access in your cPanel.
Then in your entry script (usually server.js or index.js) import `mysql` and connect like this bellow,

```
 const mysql = require('mysql');
 const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'test',
  debug: false
});
```

Please change `localhost` with your remotely accessible URL, `user`, `password` and `database` name as you have set and created in cPanel.

Comment: i have a heroku hosted api with a url like ```https://myapi.heroku.com``` ,so when adding an access host to the remote mysql if i put ```myapi.heroku.com``` will this allow my api to access the database.